# ICMP Data Being Stripped When Sending

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm working on learning about network programming as a personal project. I'm trying to just do a basic ping application at first and build on it from there. At the moment, I can send ICMP ECHO requests and receive back a reply.

The code I'm working on is below. Apologies if it's rough; it's been a few years since I've worked in C and I'm a network engineer by trade trying to dig into how things work 'under the hood.'

This is in Linux under WSL. It's possible that it's due to some quirk, but more likely just user error.

```
struct icmpdata {
        struct icmphdr hdr;
        char data[32];
} ;

unsigned short compute_checksum(unsigned short* buffer, int size) //stolen from elsewhere :( 
{
    unsigned long cksum = 0;
    while (size > 1)
    {
        cksum += *buffer++;
        size -= sizeof(unsigned short);
    }
    if (size)
    {
        cksum += *(char*)buffer;
    }

    cksum = (cksum >> 16) + (cksum & 0xffff);
    cksum += (cksum >> 16);
    return (unsigned short)(~cksum);
}

struct icmpdata * buildRequestPacket () {
        struct icmpdata * icmp_data = malloc(sizeof(struct icmpdata));
        memset(icmp_data, 0, sizeof(struct icmpdata));
        
        icmp_data->hdr.type = 8;
        icmp_data->hdr.code = 0;
        icmp_data->hdr.checksum = 0;
        icmp_data->hdr.un.echo.id = 0;
        icmp_data->hdr.un.echo.sequence = 1;
        memcpy(icmp_data->data, "Hello, world!\0", sizeof("Hello, world!\0"));
        
        icmp_data->hdr.checksum = compute_checksum((short unsigned int *)&(icmp_data->hdr), sizeof(struct icmphdr));
        
        return icmp_data;
}


struct iphdr * buildIPHeader () { // for traceroute later
return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        struct addrinfo hints, * res; 
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo)); 
        getaddrinfo(argv[1], "0", &hints, &res); //does enough to resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1


        struct icmpdata * icmp_data = buildRequestPacket();
        int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);

        void * recvbuffer = (void*)malloc(128);

        while(1) {
                sendto(sockfd, icmp_data, sizeof(icmp_data), 0, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
                recvfrom(sockfd, recvbuffer, 128, 0, NULL, 0);
        }

        printf("%s", strerror(errno));
}
```

I wanted to add on information in the data field and print the reply to screen to know I received it.

When I run sendto() I noticed that the data field I've added in a struct I've created is stripped completely and only the header is sent, to the point where if I compute the checksum with the data included, I won't receive a reply due to invalid checksum.

Likewise Wireshark only shows the ICMP header going out. I've verified I can see a data field using Linux's normal ping utility, which I'm trying to mirror (mainly the timestamp included).

I appreciate any help or guidance y'all can provide.

Comment: `sendto(sockfd, icmp_data, sizeof(icmp_data)...` looks wrong. `icmp_data` is a pointer variable, and probably has a size of 4 or 8 bytes. You probably want `sizeof *icmp_data`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the sizeof. I needed to just change it to sizeof(struct icmpdata), which is what it should've been. Completely glossed over that. Looks to be working now. This was driving me nuts; thanks a ton.

Comment: No problem. Note that there are two syntaxes for `sizeof`: `sizeof expression`, and `sizeof(type)`. The reason why your original compiled ok was that an expression in parentheses is also an expression. A lot of people don't know that, and treat `sizeof()` almost like a function call. Anyway, just a note of interest.